# Spock test returns a null model

Tags: grails, spock

The problem is quite odd, since almost the same action returns the correct model with the difference that I'm not rendering a template but view.

First the **controller** action:

The rendered model exist here as you can see

[image: author model exists]

```
def saveAjax(Author authorInstance){
    if(!authorInstance.validate()){
        respond view: 'index', authorInstance.errors
    } else {
        def author = new Author(username: authorInstance.username)
        authorService.save(author)
        render(template: 'author_row', model:[author:author]) //<--here the model is correct           
    }
}
```

If I swap '**template**' with '**view**', the test passes

The **service**:

```
Author save(Author author) {
    return author?.save(flush: true)
}
```

The **test** itself:

```
void "Test the saveAjax action"() {

    when:"you do not have the correct params"
        controller.saveAjax(new Author())

    then:"expect to be redirected to index"
        view == 'index'

    when:"you have the correct params"
        response.reset()
        controller.saveAjax(new Author(username: "Alice"))

    then:"expect to have model author"
        model.author //<-- here I get author = null
}
```

The **error**:

[image: author_is_null]

```
Condition not satisfied:

model.author
|     |
|     null
[authorInstance:daily.journal.Author : (unsaved)]
```

I know that you could check the content of the rendered template but I am explicitly aiming for the model. Is there any chance of testing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I hit upon a Grails *convention over configuration* thingy. Despite that the model is named author, it could be tested only as author**Instance**. So I changed it to:

```
then:"expect to have model author"
      model.authorInstance
```

in the spec and...it **passed**. Still I will be glad if someone could explain to me why?

Answer (score 0):

Because your author hasn't passed validation. As you can see here: `authorInstance:daily.journal.Author : (unsaved)`. 
It is unsaved due to validation error, you can update you service to

```
return author?.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
```

to receive exception on validation, or you can println your errors in test.

Comment: How would you explain this:
When I put "Instance" at the end of model.author it passes?

Comment: respond view: 'index', authorInstance.errors I think it generates to:
render view: 'index', model: [authorInstance: authorInstance]

Comment: Well, it validates it and the author is saved..then in the test it says it is not saved. That makes no sense does it?